# Выравнивание всех блоков по центру

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте, создаю сайт на блоках(практикую), у меня есть меню слева, и главное содержание справа, но если размер окна браузера увеличивать, то блоки растягиваются, и уезжают один влево, другой вправо. Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы они оба при уменьшении размера стягивались к середине, а не разъезжались... Расположение двух блоков фиксированное...

Comment: А почему бы вам не воспользоваться готовым CSS фреймворком?
http://habrahabr.ru/post/156747/

Comment: МОжет тебе поможет http://htmlbook.ru/samlayout/tipovye-makety/fiksirovannyi-maket-s-odnoi-kolonkoy
http://htmlbook.ru/samlayout/tipovye-makety/rezinovyi-dvukhkolonochnyi-maket

Comment: так, если вопрос исчерпан - закрой же его))примите чей-нибудь ответ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

свойство position: fixed - По своему действию это значение близко к absolute, но в отличие от него привязывается к указанной свойствами left, top, right и bottom точке на экране и не меняет своего положения при прокрутке веб-страницы.

Вы хотите получить это:

```
<style type="text/css">
   .main {
        margin: 0px auto;
        width: 935px;
    }
    .first {
        background-color: #0f6;
        float: left;
        width: 250px;
        position: fixed;
    }
    .second {
        background-color: #06f;
        margin: 50px 0 0 35px;
        float: left;
        width: 650px;
        overflow: scroll;
        height: 500px;
        position: fixed;
    }

</style>
```

но для чего вам блоки Fixed??

Comment: Спасибо.:)) Вопрос исчерпан)

Answer (score 3):

"обвернуть" элементы в `wrapper`, ему задать необходимую ширину и воспользоваться `margin: 0 auto`, как было сказано в ответе выше.

Answer (score 2):

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

Ниже простой пример. Если вы, конечно, это имели ввиду. Изображение центрируется при удалении, приближении, аля vk.com xD

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
        <title>Документ без названия</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .main {
                margin: 0px auto;
                width: 600px;
            }
            .first {
                background-color: #0f6;
                float: left;
                width: 300px;
            }
            .second {
                background-color: #06f;
                float: left;
                width: 300px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="first">
                first
            </div>
            <div class="second">
                second
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: <style type="text/css">
.main {
margin: 0px auto;
width: 100%;
}
.first {
background-color: #0f6;
width: 250px;
position: fixed;
top: 15px;
left: 15px;
}
.second {
background-color: #06f;
width: 650px;
height: 500px;
position: fixed;
top: 50px;
right: 100px;
overflow: scroll;
}
</style>


если будет так, то по центру не выравнивает.
но при уменьшении размера окна, растягивается снова.
есть ли что-то от этого?

Answer (score 2):

Наверняка, вы имели в виду не "фиксированные" (fixed), а "абсолютно позиционированные" (position: absolute;). Фиксированное расположение в данном случае не имеет никакой логики (или только меню, скажем, может быть "fixed").
Действительно, блоки нужно обернуть в отдельный контейнер и задать ему свойство margin: 0 auto; (и не забыть задать ширину отличную от 100%, иначе ничего не изменится).